# Watson API does not response when sending text made created by speech recognition

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ibm-watson

I am using chrome webkit for text recognition and IBM watson assistant. Everytime when my speech/text contains an '?' it should send the transcript content to watson via the API, but my transcript content does not get read by Watson. For a normal text entered by keyboard this piece of code works without any problems

```html
<label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
          <input id="textInput" class="input responsive-column"
            placeholder="Type something" type="text" value=""
            onkeydown="/*globals CanvasJS */
            ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)">
        </label>
```

I replaced this code with those two ones...

```html
<label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
<div id="textInput" class="input responsive-column" type="text" ></div></label>
```

```html
if(finalTranscripts.includes('?')){
           Api.sendRequest(finalTranscripts, this);


          }
```

This is the context ....

```html
<body>
  <div id="contentParent" class="responsive-columns-wrapper">
    <div id="chat-column-holder" class="responsive-column content-column">
      <div class="chat-column">
        <div id="scrollingChat"></div>

       
<label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
<div id="textInput" class="input responsive-column" type="text" ></div></label>




<button onclick="startConverting();"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></button>
<script type="text/javascript">



 var r = document.getElementById('textInput');
 function startConverting (){

  if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window){
 var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
 speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
 speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
  speechRecognizer.lang = 'en-IN';
 speechRecognizer.start();

 var finalTranscripts = '';

 speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event){
          var interimTranscripts = '';
          for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
           var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript; 
           transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
           if(event.results[i].isFinal){
            finalTranscripts += transcript;
           }else{
            interimTranscripts += transcript;
           }}
 

 if(finalTranscripts.includes('!')){
           window.alert('It works');


          }


 if(finalTranscripts.includes('?')){
           Api.sendRequest(finalTranscripts, this);


          }         

          r.innerHTML = finalTranscripts + '<span style="color#999' +interimTranscripts + '</span>'; 
 };

 speechRecognizer.onerror = function (event) {
  };



}else {
 r.innerHTML = 'please update google chrome ';
}

 }



</script>
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Like I said before, it seems that Watson is not reading the content of my speech...

(ConversationPanel and inputKeyDown is defined in an .js file)

I am happy for any kind of help.